# Apify - error in configuration of generated actor

Tags: node.js, apify

I'm trying to run Apify locally, after installing all the packages, creating the actor and running it I got this:

```
Warning: You are not logged in with your Apify Account. Some features like Apify Proxy will not work. Call "apify login" to fix that.
Run: npm start

> test2@0.0.1 start
> node main.js

/home/a/test2/node_modules/apify/build/configuration.js:91
        const envKey = Configuration.ENV_MAP_REVERSED[key] ?? key;
                                                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a/test2/node_modules/apify/build/events.js:10:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/a/test2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node main.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/a/.npm/_logs/2022-02-08T18_28_58_177Z-debug.log
Error: npm exited with code 1
```

the version of npm is v12.22.5
Any ideas how to generate the correct config file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need Node.js 16+ for the latest SDK to work